# Xamarin page constrution XML and code behind

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, menu, grid

I am trying to create a menu page where I need to keep a button on screen even if a scroll, like button stops at the edge of the screen, and I have this layout in XML but I needed it in code behind to add some frame dynamic. This is what I made but it's not show up the same. Any suggestions please?

```
<Grid RowSpacing="0" ColumnSpacing="0">
        <Grid.Margin>
            <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="Thickness">
                <On Platform="iOS" Value="0,20,0,0" />
            </OnPlatform>
        </Grid.Margin>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Label Text="FIXED HEADER DEMO" Margin="12" Grid.Row="0" FontSize="14" />
        <Grid x:Name="ContentGrid" RowSpacing="0" ColumnSpacing="0" Grid.Row="1">
            <ScrollView x:Name="TheScroll">
                <Grid RowSpacing="0" ColumnSpacing="0">
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition x:Name="ImageRow" Height="Auto" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Image x:Name="BearImage" Source="bear.jpg"
                           Aspect="AspectFill"
                           Grid.Row="0" />
                    <Label LineBreakMode="WordWrap"
                           Margin="12,5,12,5"
                           Grid.Row="1">
                           Text="abc"
                    </Label>
                </Grid>
            </ScrollView>

            <Label x:Name="TitleText"
                   Text="Bear found in the wild!"
                   TextColor="White"
                   BackgroundColor="#FF264778"
                   HeightRequest="40"
                   VerticalOptions="Start" VerticalTextAlignment="Center"                   
                   HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" />
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
```

My code behind

```
 public void PageConstructor()
        {


            Grid thirdG = new Grid
            {
                RowDefinitions =
                {
                    new RowDefinition { Height = new GridLength(1,GridUnitType.Auto) },
                    new RowDefinition { Height = new GridLength(1,GridUnitType.Star) },
                },
            };



            var image1 = new Image
            {
                Source = "bear.jpg",
            };
            var labeltext = new Label
            {
                LineBreakMode = LineBreakMode.WordWrap,
                Text = msg + msg2 + msg3,
            };
            thirdG.Children.Add(image1, 0, 0);
            thirdG.Children.Add(labeltext, 0, 1);



            Grid secondG = new Grid
            {


            };

            SecondTitle= new Label { Text = "Second title text", TextColor = Color.Black };
            scrollV = new ScrollView { Content = thirdG };

            secondG.Children.Add(SecondTitle);

            secondG.Children.AddVertical(scrollV);



            Grid firstG = new Grid
            {
                RowDefinitions =
                {
                    new RowDefinition { Height = new GridLength(1,GridUnitType.Auto) },
                    new RowDefinition { Height = new GridLength(1,GridUnitType.Star) },
                },
            };

            firstG.Children.Add(new Label { Text = "Title" }, 0, 0);
            firstG.Children.Add(secondG, 0, 1);




            Content = firstG;



        }
```

Comment: you can build your layout in XAML and then modify it in the code behind.  You don't have to pick one or the other, you can combine the approaches.

Comment: Ok. So can I add a scroll view in a Grid cell? Like bind it or how i add it?

Comment: You could just do that in the XAML.  Or do `myGrid.Children.Add(view,col,row);`

Answer (score 0):

According to your code, I find you use ScrollView in Grid, it will be covered by label TitleText, so I suggest you can put scrollview outside the grid

```
        <Grid>

        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Label
            Grid.Row="0"
            Margin="12"
            FontSize="14"
            Text="FIXED HEADER DEMO" />
        <ScrollView Grid.Row="1">
            <Grid x:Name="ContentGrid">

                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition x:Name="ImageRow" Height="Auto" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                <Image
                    x:Name="BearImage"
                    Grid.Row="0"
                    HeightRequest="50"
                    Source="a11.jpg"
                    WidthRequest="50" />
                <Label
                    Grid.Row="1"
                    Margin="12,5,12,5"
                    LineBreakMode="WordWrap">
                    Text=&quot;abc&quot;
                </Label>
                <Label
                    x:Name="TitleText"
                    BackgroundColor="#FF264778"
                    HeightRequest="40"
                    HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                    Text="Bear found in the wild!"
                    TextColor="White"
                    VerticalOptions="Start"
                    VerticalTextAlignment="Center" />
            </Grid>
        </ScrollView>
    </Grid>
```

Same effect in code behind:

```
public Page3()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

      
        var image1 = new Image
        {
            Source = "a11.jpg",WidthRequest=70,HeightRequest=70
        };

        var label1 = new Label
        {
            Text = "abc"
        };

        var label2 = new Label
        {
            Text = "Bear found in the wild!",HeightRequest=20,VerticalTextAlignment=TextAlignment.Center,HorizontalTextAlignment=TextAlignment.Center
        };
        Grid secondG = new Grid
        {

            RowDefinitions =
            {
                new RowDefinition { Height = new GridLength(1,GridUnitType.Auto) },
                new RowDefinition { Height = new GridLength(1,GridUnitType.Star) },
            },
        };      
       var scrollV = new ScrollView { Content = secondG };

        secondG.Children.Add(image1,0,0);

        secondG.Children.Add(label1,0,1);
        secondG.Children.Add(label2);
        Grid firstG = new Grid
        {
            RowDefinitions =
            {
                new RowDefinition { Height = new GridLength(1,GridUnitType.Auto) },
                new RowDefinition { Height = new GridLength(1,GridUnitType.Star) },
            },
        };
        var labeltext = new Label
        {
            LineBreakMode = LineBreakMode.WordWrap,FontSize=14,
            Text = "FIXED HEADER DEMO"
        };
        firstG.Children.Add(labeltext, 0, 0);
        firstG.Children.Add(scrollV, 0, 1);
        Content = firstG;
    }
}
```